# Greiner-Hormann clipping problem

Tags: 3d, projection, clipping

I have a set of planar polygons in 3D space defined by their vertices in **counterclockwise** order. Let's define the 'positive face' as being the face of the 3D polygon such as when observed, the vertices appear in **counterclockwise** order, and the 'negative face', the face which when observed, the vertices appear in **clockwise** order.

I'm doing perspective projection of the set of polygons onto a *projection* polygon defined by the points in this order: (0, h, 0), (0, 0, 0), (w, 0, 0), and (w, h, 0), where w and h are strictly positive integers. The positive face of this projection polygon is oriented towards positive Z, and the camera point is somewhere at (0, 0, d), where d is a strictly negative number.

In order to 'clip' the projected polygons into the projection polygon, I'm applying the [Greiner-Hormann](http://www.inf.usi.ch/hormann/papers/Greiner.1998.ECO.pdf) (PDF) clipping algorithm, which requires that the clipper and the to-be-clipped polygons be in the same order (i.e. clockwise or counterclockwise).

My question is the following:

How can I determine whether the projected face of the 3D polygon is the negative or the positive one? Meaning, how do I find out if I have to work with the vertices in normal or inverted order for the algorithm to work?

I noticed that only if the 3D polygon is facing the projection polygon with its negative face, both of them are in the same order (counterclockwise), otherwise, a modification needs to be done.

Here is a picture that illustrates this:

[image]

Note that the planes described by the polygon from the set and the projection polygon may not always be parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given three points of the polygon in normal order `p0`, `p1`, `p2`

1. Calculate the direction of the normal of the plane the triangle defined by points p0, p1, p2 lies in:

   ```
   normal_direction = cross(p0 - p1, p2 - p1)
   ```

   Do it for both polygons, the projection polygon and the 3D polygon in question
2. Take the dot product of the normal of both polygons. if the dot-product is bigger or equal 0, both are in the same order. If it is smaller than zero, you need to inverse the order of the points.